# How can I set a Dashboard to just Specific Users?

Tags: lightning, reporting, user, dashboard

I was just asked by my Director of Sales to set a Specific Dashboard for him and one other user. The dashboard is created, but I cannot find a way to set it to their home. I found a way to do so in Classic, but we are on Lightning.

Comment: Because a dashboard is just a high overview of data, it's very rare someone needs to see it more than once a day. With that said, why not schedule the dashboard to be emailed to these users instead of setting it on the homepage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of assigning particular dashboard in lightning as homepage by users is still in the consideration phase

Here is the idea link

[Allow users to select a dashboard on their lightning home page](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003X41QAE)

Please up-vote if it is relevant to you